# Intersection function for Integer Set

Tags: scala, tree, set, binary-tree

So basically I am implementing sets of integers using binary tree.

Here's the abstract class IntSet

```
abstract class IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean
   def union(other: IntSet): IntSet
   def intersect(other: IntSet) : IntSet
}
```

NonEmpty set:

```
/********************NonEmpty************************************/
class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left contains x
    else if (x > elem) right contains x
    else true
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet =
    if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right)
    else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
    else this

     override def toString = "{" + left + elem + right + "}"

    def union(other: IntSet): IntSet= {
    ((left union right) union other) incl elem
    }

}
```

And EmptySet:

```
/********************Empty************************************/
class Empty extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, new Empty, new Empty)
  def union(other: IntSet): IntSet = other
  override def toString = "."
}
```

As you can see, union of two sets has been implemented. 
My question is that how would I go with implementing the intersection function?

Union work fine as you can see from the output:

```
val t1=  new NonEmpty(1, new NonEmpty(2, new Empty(), new Empty()),  new NonEmpty(3, new Empty(), new Empty()))
                                                  //> t1  : mid.NonEmpty = {{.2.}1{.3.}}
val t2 =new NonEmpty(5, new NonEmpty(6, new Empty(), new Empty()),  new NonEmpty(7, new Empty(), new Empty()))
                                                  //> t2  : mid.NonEmpty = {{.6.}5{.7.}}
          //t1 union t2                           //> res0: mid.IntSet = {{{{.1.}2{.3.}}6.}5{.7.}}
```

Comment: Why not use `TreeSet` from the Scala standard library? It should be specialized for `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Trivial implementaion for `Empty` class:

```
class Empty extends IntSet {
  override def intersect(other: IntSet): IntSet = new Empty
}
```

Recursion implementation for `NonEmpty` (be attentive: all constructor arguments mark as `val`):

```
class NonEmpty(val elem: Int, val left: IntSet, val right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
  override def intersect(other: IntSet): IntSet = {
    def intersect(set: IntSet, result: IntSet): IntSet = {
      set match {
        case e: Empty => result
        case e: NonEmpty =>
          val afterLeft = intersect(e.left, result)
          val afterRight = intersect(e.right, afterLeft)
          if (other.contains(e.elem)) afterRight.incl(e.elem)
          else afterRight
      }
    }

    intersect(this, new Empty)
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
val e1 = new Empty().incl(1).incl(2).incl(3).incl(5).incl(9).incl(4).incl(7)
e1: IntSet = {.1{.2{.3{{.4.}5{{.7.}9.}}}}}
val e2 = new Empty().incl(1).incl(3).incl(7).incl(9)
e2: IntSet = {.1{.3{.7{.9.}}}}
e1.intersect(e2)
res0: IntSet = {{{.1.}3.}7{.9.}}
e2.intersect(e1)
res1: IntSet = {{{{.1.}3.}7.}9.}
```

Possible improvements:

- replace `abstract class` with `sealed trait`
- replace `class Empty` with `object Empty`
- replace `class NonEmpty` with `сase class NonEmpty`

Answer (score 1):

```
def intersection(x: IntSet) : IntSet =
{
    val y = if (x contains elem) new NonEmpty(elem, new Empty, new Empty)
            else new Empty

    y union ((left intersection x) union (right intersection x))
}
```